# How can i create SQL Connection in Durable Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In my Activity Function, when I am using ConfigurationManager it's not working. Can you suggest any other way to achieve the application setting and setting for the SQL Connection?

I am using below code to connect to SQL Database.

```
 public static DataTable getDataFromSql()

 {


   var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XYZ"].ConnectionString;

   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

   using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))

   {

      string oString = $"SELECT * FROM TableName";

      SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
      myConnection.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(oCmd);
      da.Fill(dataTable);
      myConnection.Close();
      da.Dispose();
  }
  return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use below code to achieve application setting:

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
     return name + ": " +
    System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}
```

More information for your reference:

[Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#environment-variables)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After getting the value of variable how can I connect to SQL Connection?

Comment: @SumitGarg We can connect to SQL Database using the code you posted above. [SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con);  myConnection.Open();]

Comment: it is not working. i am getting
[Error] run.csx(37,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
i am also using the assembly System.Data.dll

Comment: @SumitGarg I have tested and it worked. About how to add reference to azure function, we can refer to: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/13/how-to-add-assembly-references-to-an-azure-function-app/

Comment: @SumitGarg Did you use the correct assembly? For .NET core or .NET Framework? I suggest that use Visual Studio to create the Azure function and use correct assembly, then publish it to Azure via Visual Studio.

Comment: @SumitGarg For example, if you used .NET core in your function, you need to use the assembly System.Data.SqlClient.dll of .Net standard 2.0. This assembly is located at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.data.sqlclient\4.4.3\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll] of your computer if you have installed the .Net core

Comment: i am usnig azure portal and i am using function version 2 so where can i find these?

Comment: @SumitGarg As you are using function version 2, you used .NET core to develop your function. So you need the assembly of [System.Data.SqlClient.dll]. We can download .NET core SDK at https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.4 and we can get this assembly at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.data.sqlclient\4.4.3\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll]